# Why the nodes in a Boltzmann machine need to be sampled one at a time?

Tags: sampling, gibbs, markov-random-field

Typically, we use Gibbs sampling to update (or generate samples from) energy based models. This means we update each node while keeping its markov blanket constant.

Why can't we update/sample all the nodes at the same time?

If your answer is “because otherwise we can't reach thermal equilibrium”, then why can't we reach thermal equilibrium?

Comment: To rephrase my question: What would go wrong (and why), if we used the conditional distributions to update all nodes at once?

Comment: Sure, but how would this update scheme differ from Gibbs update scheme in practice? For example, would this suffer from some kind of bias in the samples it generates, compared to Gibbs sampling? and why?

Comment: Yes, I know what Gibbs sampling is. My question is _how_ would the distribution of the generated samples be different between these two updating schemes.